# PHP Weird output by simple code

Tags: php

I have this code with me and it is giving "aababc" in output i am not sure why this behaving like this.

```
<?php
    $str = ‘abcdefghijklmnop’;
    $fp = fopen(“output.txt”, ‘w’);
    for($i=0; $i< 4; $i++) {
    fwrite($fp, $str, $i);
    }
    ?>
```

Any Guru having any idea on this.

Thanks

Comment: What did you expect it to write?

Comment: Well, the 3rd parameter of fwrite is a length limit, so basically your code writes to output.txt:

the first letter (i = 0, a)
then the first 2 letters (i = 1, ab)
and finally, when i = 3 it writes:
abc
with results: aababc.

if you wanted to write the first 3 letters of your $str you should:

fwrite($fp, $str[$i]);

good luck.

Comment: It should write abc..

Answer (score 4):

Here how your **for**-loop works:

```
// i = 0;
fwrite($fp, $str, 0); // writes nothing
// i = 1;
fwrite($fp, $str, 1); // writes a
// i = 2;
fwrite($fp, $str, 2); // writes ab
// i = 3;
fwrite($fp, $str, 3); // writes abc
// total write 'aababc'
```

**UPDATE:** And to achive your goal:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
   fwrite($fp, substr($str, $i, 1));
}
// will write 'abcd'
```

I cant stop) Or without loop:

```
// will take 3 first symbols from string and write to file
fwrite($fp, substr($str, 0, 3));
// will write 3 symbols from string to file
fwrite($fp, $str, 3);
```

Comment: use `substr` to get the proper symbol you need

Answer (score 1):

It behaves correctly.

i = 0
str = ''

i = 1
str = 'a'

i = 2
str = 'ab'

i = 3
str = 'abc'

so it writes to the end of it every time what's in $str until length $i.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the fwrite from this

```
fwrite($fp, $str, $i);
```

to this:

```
fwrite($fp, substr($str, $i, 1));
```

To get the expected result 'abc'

Comment: Nope( `substr($str, $i, 1)` is better)